# I want Scrapy to run through each item once

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

I would like Scrapy to run through each item once so that relevant data is grouped together. As it is it just puts all links, headers, dates etc together. It is also posting everything to the file more than once. I am pretty new to both Scrapy and Python so any advice I would be grateful for.

Here is my spider code:

```
from scrapy.spiders import Spider 
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from fashioBlog.functions import extract_data

from fashioBlog.items import Fashioblog

class firstSpider(Spider):
   name = "first"
   allowed_domains = [
      "stopitrightnow.com"

   ]
   start_urls = [
      "http://www.stopitrightnow.com"

   ]




def parse(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    sites = sel.xpath('//div[@class="post-outer"]')
    items= []

    for site in sites:
        item = Fashioblog()

        item['title'] = extract_data(site.xpath('//h3[normalize-space(@class)="post-title entry-title"]//text()').extract())
        item['url'] = extract_data(site.xpath('//div[normalize-space(@class)="post-body entry-content"]//@href').extract())
        item['date'] = extract_data(site.xpath('//h2[normalize-space(@class)="date-header"]/span/text()').extract())
        #item['body'] = site.xpath('//div[@class="post-body entry-content"]/i/text()').extract()
        item['labelLink'] = extract_data(site.xpath('//span[normalize-space(@class)="post-labels"]//@href').extract())
        item['comment'] = extract_data(site.xpath('//span[normalize-space(@class)="post-comment-link"]//text()').extract())
        item['picUrl'] = extract_data(site.xpath('//div[normalize-space(@class)="separator"]//@href').extract())
        #item['labelText'] = extract_data(site.xpath('(//i//text()').extract())
        #item['labelLink2'] = extract_data(site.xpath('(//i//@href').extract())
        yield item
```

Comment: Did you check item pipeline feature for skipping duplicates?[link](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html) can you post example of what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your expressions **context-specific** by prepending a dot:

```
item['title'] = extract_data(site.xpath('.//h3[normalize-space(@class)="post-title entry-title"]//text()').extract())
                                         ^ HERE
```

Comment: Okay so that has ordered the data in a manner that better mirrors the website, which is what I wanted so thank you. Is there a way to organise the data so that it is easier to read? Currently each piece of data is appended to the next so it's a mess.

Comment: Can we see the code from the "extract_data" function? Not sure what it's doing. You don't need that to extract the text from the xpath. Also try changing // to / from the ends of the xpath expressions you just need .// in the beginning.